# Was the 'green screen' in the troop carrier, night vision?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

As Rita, William and J squad are travelling over Paris toward The Louvre at night, there is a shot showing the inside of the cockpit and the front window with a HUD.

[image: Green Screen HUD in the troop carrier]

Oh that's handy, they have night vision, that'll help with the surprise aspect of this mission.  But just moments later, we see..

[image: Troop carrier with 6 visible airframe lights and a SPOT-LIGHT that could be the bat signal]

Never mind the 6 lights still lit on the troop carrier itself, that spotlight could be the Bat Signal.

Is the green screen night vision, and if so, why on Earth would they be coming in with a very bright spot light blasting a light-show into the dark night?

Comment: Possibly it was a UV or Infrared light. That they would hope would not be visible to the aliens, but would be visible to the troops with UV or Infrared capabilities in their goggles/helmets.  The use of such devices have been used in modern armies when fighting less equipped ones.

Comment: @DoscoJones Please don't make invalid edits.  British spelling is *not* incorrect so please stop changing it.

Comment: @NJohnny Please enter that as an answer. Perhaps flesh it out a little first. They're good points that, while not definitive, are certainly plausible.

Comment: Could be aliens see a bit more into UV side, so reddish or even yellow light could be invisible for them.